# Paypal Credit Card Processing

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to make a feature in site that accepts the credit card. I don't want to use stripe. But is there anyway I can process and checkout using only credit card but not using paypal account/credit via Paypal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a number of options for this.

- [PayPal Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/)
- [PayPal REST Direct Credit Cards](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/credit-card-payments/)
- [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/en-gb/products/braintree-direct)

If you are working with PHP I'd recommend Payments Pro and then using our [PHP class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to integrate it.  As a PayPal Partner I can get the monthly fee for Pro waived for you if you're using our library.  [Contact me directly](https://www.angelleye.com/contact-us) for details.